# Active Reports 2.0 License Issue Watermark in Reports

Tags: vb6, activereports

I created an installer referencing the dll’s of the installed active reports (already licensed).
But when I install my project in a new machine, there is a watermark in the reports.
Please advise how to remove the watermark.

I tried everything but with no luck. I don’t know what causing this issue, i didn’t include the dll’s in my installer packager but i still encountered the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming this ActiveReports v2 Com version.

The assemblies are not licensed.  The machine on which the product is installed is licensed.  To test that, run one of the samples from the installer and see if you get the evaluation version or not.

If the project compilation on a licensed machine goes fine, the license information is embedded in that excutable.  When you deploy, the ACtiveReports* assemblies that were part of the project also needs deployed aling with executable.

On a machine that dose not has ActiveReports installed, the application executable will look in the same folder as the exe for references.

Can you re-check and update.  If there is a screenshot that you can share, that will help too.  Also, update with the build number.

Comment: @RajnishSinsha will give you update, ill test thanks

Answer (score 0):

Issue is already solved, I just acquired a copy of license registry and register it in my local PC. So frustrating that the solution is just too simple @.@